# How to add padding to UIBarButtonItem programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I added `UINavigationBar` programmatically using this code in `viewDidLoad()`

```
let navbar = UINavigationBar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 59.0))
    self.view.addSubview(navbar)
```

and then I added two button which I need using this code:

```
let item = UINavigationItem()
    item.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style: .Done, target: self, action: #selector(CollectionCollectionViewController.goBack(_:)))

    item.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Add, target: self, action: #selector(CollectionCollectionViewController.addProduct(_:)))

    navbar.setItems([item], animated: true)
```

Everything works great, but this buttons are very close to right and left edge of screen. How can I add padding ( or margin left and right)to this buttons?

It looks like that:

[image]

I see that,this spacing between buttons and screen is only one time when I launch this `ViewController`, when I launch it second time, spacing between buttons and screen is correct. Can somebody explain me why?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your navigation bar's *frame* is responsible for your unexpected missing spacing. Its `x` position is 0 and its width is the same as the view controller's width. Hence there's no spacing.

I would suggest to add a navigation bar in the view controller's storyboard instead. In most cases it's preferable to solve as many UI problems as possible in the storyboard as it reduces your amount of code to read and maintain.

However, if you want to find out the correct frame placement and dimensions for a navigation bar you can print the navigation bar's frame. Then you compare its frame when it appears without spacing with its frame when it has its correct position. You can then adjust its `x` position and `width` accordingly.

Comment: It is one of options, but I want to add everything in my project programmatically. And in this case I have problem and don't have any idea why...

Comment: I did It and the result is the same in both variants `(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 59.0)`. I add that I try to add navbar to CollectionViewController

Answer (score 0):

I have solution for my problem. If we want to add navbar programmatically from scratch, we need to make this steps in `viewDidLoad()`:

```
    // setp 1 = create Navigation Bar

    let navbar = UINavigationBar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 59.0))
    navbar.delegate = self

    //step 2 = create Navigation Item

    let item = UINavigationItem()
    item.title = "Quick choise"


    //step 3 = create BarButtonItem and set position (left, right)

    let leftButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style: .Done, target: self, action: #selector(CollectionCollectionViewController.goBack(_:)))
    item.leftBarButtonItem = leftButton


    let rightButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Add, target: self, action: #selector(CollectionCollectionViewController.addProduct(_:)))
    item.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton

    //step 4 = add BarButtonItems to Navigation Bar

    navbar.items = [item]

    //step 5 = add Navigation Bar to view

    self.view.addSubview(navbar)
```